# Firebase + React - Not changing my state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this block of code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.database();
    let dbRefRoot = db.ref().child('sponnsor');

    dbRefRoot.child('test').on('value', snap => {
        let userData = snap.val();
        console.log('test', userData );

        this.setState({
            test: snap.val()
        })
    })

}
```

And I just would like be sure that is working and I'm going on right direction! Because every time that I update my information on Firebase, nothing happen! I was expecting see my console log working! It isn't, and I cant understand why.

ps: Im importing: import * as firebase from 'firebase';

My obj:

```js
{
 "sponnsor": {
  "test": 1234
 }
}
```

Comment: No typo in `child('sponnsor')`? `sponsor` maybe?

Comment: sponnsor it is correct, is the name of project! With double NN ... hehe.. 
www.sponnsor.com

Answer (score 1):

Updating is very simple like this

```
firebase.database().ref('sponnsor')
.update({test:3456})
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have published your object structure I think you should do as:

```
let dbRefRoot = db.ref().child('sponnsor');

dbRefRoot.on('value', snap => {
    let sponnsorData = snap.val();
    console.log('test', sponnsorData.test );

    this.setState({
        test: sponnsorData.test
    })
})
```